# unable to find the string in java

Tags: java

I am trying to find the particular word in string array. If the word matches means i want to add new number next to that word. Here is my program.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Pincode {

  public static String udf_pincode(String input) throws IOException 
  {
    System.out.println("Inside the function::"+ input);
    String[] Address = input.split("");

    if(Address.equals("Adambakkam"))
    {
        String pincode = "600028";
        double pin = Double.parseDouble(pincode);
        //String pin = pincode.toString()+"adam";

       // return pin;
    }
    else if(Address.equals("Adyar"))
    {
        String pincode = "600088";
        double pin = Double.parseDouble(pincode);
        //  String pin = pincode.toString();
        // return pin;    
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("Inside the function");
    String res = udf_pincode("Adambakkam");
    System.out.println("Output::" + res);
  }
}
```

the data looks like this..

```
 chennai
 madurai
 bangalore
 hyderabad
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell how  `String[] Address= input.split("");` look like when data is there?

Comment: the data looks like this...

Comment: Is your `String[]` contains `Adambakkam` and  `Adyar` ?

Comment: the data is in columns..so 1st row contains adambakkam..2nd row contains adyar

Comment: yes.................

Comment: Also is your code compiled? add `return` in `udf_pincode(String input)` method

Comment: On the line if(Address.equals("Adambakkam")), you are comparing a String array with a String.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your code

```
String[] Address = input.split(" ");

List<String> addressList= Arrays.asList(Address);

if (addressList.contains("Adambakkam"))
{
//code here
}
```

and pass your inputs as separated by a single space like `Delhi Mumbai`

For reading data row wise example form a file then use the below lines

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/of/text"));
String str;

List<String> addressList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
    addressList.add(str);
}

if (addressList.contains("Adambakkam"))
{
//code here
}
```

Comment: Hi my data is in row wise.i dont know how to split the data.

Comment: @sharonpaul please let me know how you are passing the input are you using some file containing the lines of input, in that case you can use the above method of reading the file and using it.

Answer (score 0):

As `@JamesB` mentioned your code will like this

```
  package com.test.tree;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class StringTest {

        public static String udf_pincode(String input) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Inside the function::" + input);
            String[] Address = input.split("");
            for(String address : Address){
            if (address.equals("Adambakkam")) {
                String pincode = "600028";
                double pin = Double.parseDouble(pincode);
                // String pin = pincode.toString()+"adam";

                // return pin;
            } else if (address.equals("Adyar")) {
                String pincode = "600088";
                double pin = Double.parseDouble(pincode);
                // String pin = pincode.toString();
                // return pin;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
            }
            return input;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Inside the function");
            String res = udf_pincode("Adambakkam");
            System.out.println("Output::" + res);
        }
    }
```